# leaflet "src/map/Map.js" => 404 in "downloaded version" !? Bug?

Tags: leaflet, http-status-code-404, src

try at time to install an easy "downloaded version" of leafelet to make my own app, but have absolutely no access, because I run from one error to the next.

First, the idea with the simple package is great for not Linux nerds! Thank you!
But, here it would be nice, if also the index.html and the index.js also would be included and ready to run (Path: "./"). So if upcoming an error, the user knows, there is an problem with the server, not with the code at first.

I was try to type in the both files abd getting in the console a 404 error because
"src/map/Map.js" isn't found. So, yes! It's correct because no sript here should be searching anything in /src/. :(

Is this a bug in version 1.9.4?
What can I do?

My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Leaflet Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="./leaflet.css"
    />
    <script src="./leaflet.js" ></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My index.js

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '© OpenStreetMap'
}).addTo(map);
```

Is my first simple Experiment so far, but nothing is running... ;(

Was build my app version on codesandbox.io and there is running with no problems, but to code it on the own server ... ups! Nothing is working as expected.

Comment: Also in 1.8.0 it is so...
What can I do???

Comment: Chrome is anry about first line in html... delete and seems ok.
Have now used web repository links to leaflet script, but no map and only this in the console:
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj/browser-polyfill.js.map: Systemfehler: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Has anyone a working Package for me so I can test it and also could use it as base code?

Comment: Ok, is running now, but really only per web repository loaded script.
In the downloaded script is anything wrong so it seems.
Everytime errors because not available path /src/... .

Comment: What do the first lines in your `leaflet.js` file look like?

Comment: Ok, seems, it needs a folder where JS is located.
In same level of index files isn't running, but Leaflet in folder works now. :D
Or the ./ is the problem and without it would work...?